# http post request help

Tags: php, http, httprequest

I have done a simple web page in php to test post request from telnet.
Here is the code of the web page (example.php):

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="example.php>">
Your Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="Name"><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form> 
<?php echo $_POST["Name"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This works from the browser, but I would like to test it from telnet. I tried:

```
telnet localhost 80
POST example.php HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 11

Name=myname
```

But it doesn't work....any help?

Comment: Either look at Fiddler or Wireshark and see what a real POST packet contains, or read the RFC a bit more deeply ;)

Comment: "But it doesn't work...." sorry, but this is not a good kind of error message. - tell us more about reactions and behavior of the system. check the webserver-access/error log, and so on.

Comment: yes, you are right...i will try to dig a bit deeper :) anyway the response from server was a HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: I'd recommend curl, which is a bit more user friendly for testing HTTP requests: `curl http://localhost/example.php -d 'Name=myname'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your content-type

```
POST /example.php HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 11

Name=myname
```

Answer (score 4):

Konerak is right. Take a look at a real request. For instance the Content-Type. I just gave it a try and got

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

You are also missing the second form field: your button. But I guess that does not matter...

```
Name=myname&submit=submit
```

take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29 for some more details and a good starting point for your research...

**Update**: try

```
POST /example.php HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 11

Name=myname
```

at least, this worked for me...